# Indices Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For these equations $n$, $m$, $p$, and $k$ are positive integers greater than $1$.

$$n^{5/3}=m^{7/2}$$
$$nm=p^k$$

What is the smallest value that $k$ can be?

Answer is $31$.

I got as far as $mn=n^{31/21}=m^{31/10}=p^k$. Don't know how to finish it off from here.

Comment: Oh wait my result is wrong. I've fixed it now.

Comment: Do you still need an answer?